# For small amounts of unexpected expenses, do contractors normally provide proof with invoices?

Tags: salary, contractors, expenses, invoices

I was provided with equipment that started having issues charging. My manager told me to call the tech support line. The number was in a different country. I was charged about $15. The manager said if this happened I could invoice for it. Is it normal to provide proof for small expenses like this i.e. my phone bill?

As an aside, some people say it's wrong to use the word "manager" when working as a contractor. So what then do you call it? This is more of a consulting firm and the actual work has been contracted out on several levels. The "managers" official title is "president of the consulting firm".

Comment: I think "supervisor" is the most applicable word of you want to refer to the person who directs what a contractor does.

Comment: The term contractor could be confusing if you’re not actually working in construction.

Comment: @AsheraH that must be a cultural thing, widely used term in the UK.

Comment: @AsheraH And in Australia.

Comment: @AsheraH, I'm referred to as a contractor while doing software development in the US. It's pretty common here for any "gig" worker to be considered a contractor.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is absolutely normal, and very much above board.  You maintain a paper trail, and everyone is happy.

Comment: Just invoice them without any proof. If they ask for it, sending through a screenshot of the single line entry in your phone bill should be enough. No need to provide all your phone log information.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming that the company trusts you to be honest: They can't just hand out £15 but need some invoice for tax reason. If *you* give them a piece of paper that you paid £15 in phone charges, that's enough for the company for tax purposes.

On the other hand, when you do your own taxes, and you have no proof of the expense, the £15 will be seen as profit and you have to pay tax on it. Still, better to get £15 and pay tax on it than not to get £15.